# Multiple Django Apps using one database/model

Tags: python, django, django-models

New to Django...I'm trying to create a project with the following structure:

```
CompanyName <--Project
  ingredients < -- Application
  CompanyName
  supplier <-- Application
```

My issue is that my project is going to use a database/model like the following:

```
  suppliers (table)
    - name
    - created_by (foreign_key, auth.User)
  ingredients (table)
    - name
    - supplied_by (foreign_key, supplier.name)
```

My question is do I create all the tables in a single models.py or do I break up each table into each application's manage.py?  If I use separate models.py, how do you create the suppliers table and then the ingredients table since the ingredients table has a foreign key  to suppliers?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my thought:

1. You can create both in the same models.py. You should separate it into a separate app when it has special and complete functionality.
2. You can refer to a forigen key found in another app.
   See here (4th example): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey
   This will not cause you a problem because the tables are not created until you run:

`makemigrations`

`migrate`